# Configure the embedded queue in the Seize block

Tags: anylogic

the documentation of the Seize block says:

“The rich interface of Queue (ability to use priorities, timeouts, remove agents, etc.) is fully exposed by Seize.”

Where can I configure that queue? I need to configure that queue in order to choose the preferred agent by comparison as queue blocks allow:

[queue block configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gcRDN.png)

But I can’t find that “rich interface” of the queue blocks in the interface of the size block.
Also, I see that the queue blocks have great logs like the statistics_log. How can I add the queue of the size block in that log? (I already have ticked the “Force statistics collection” for that block but still doesn’t shows in the statistics_log).

[statistics_log without size block](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qm50Q.png)

Because I wasn’t able to configure the size bock queue, I placed a queue before the size block, but the issue with that is that the queue of the size block is still active and the minimum capacity is one, so it alters the statistics of the queue block because is like having two queues as the image shows:

[seize queue has min one unit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qvdJW.png)

How can I turn off the queue of the size block?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way is to put a Queue block before a Seize block. You cannot actually reduce the Seize`s queue capacity below 1. But setting it to 1 basically renders that queue irrelevant.

When you want to compute your actual queue statistics, you can add "1" to the upstream Queue block if `seize.size()>1` (1 agent is seizing and 1 is in the build-in queue to seize next)

The help text isn't very good at explaining that ;)

Comment: Let's imagine a situation where we have a queue positioned before the seize block, and this queue has the timeout property activated. In such cases, it is important to note that the seize queue cannot be reduced to zero. The seize queue always has a minimum capacity of 1. If the seize queue capacity were set to zero, one agent would be taken out of the timeout property of the original queue and placed directly into the seize queue. This behavior is generally not desirable, particularly when dealing with a large number of agents or running the simulation for extended periods, such as years.